# iPhone drive removed upon installing iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows, folders

When iTunes is installed my iPhone does not appear as a drive in Windows Explorer.
When iTunes is removed, the iPhone does appear as a drive.
I use Windows 7 64bit

I would like to have iTunes to backup locally *and* have iPhone as a drive so I can download pictures from it.

How can I have both?

This may or may not be related to the following error I get after installing iTunes and attaching+detaching my iPhone via USB:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any images in your camera roll? If not it won't appear.

Comment: yes, I have a thousand